# Doubly conditional Typescript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a type based on two conditions. A basic case might be something like:

```
// Not valid TS
type DoubleCheck<T, U> = T extends number && U extends string ? SomeType : never

// Verbose TS
type DoubleCheck<T, U> = T extends number 
  ? U extends string
    ? SomeType 
    : never
  : never

DoubleCheck<0,"b"> // SomeType
DoubleCheck<"a"|0,"b"|1> // SomeType
DoubleCheck<"foo", 5> // never
DoubleCheck<undefined, "b"> // never
```

Or:

```
// Not valid TS
type HasFooString<T> = T extends SomeType && T['foo'] extends string ? TypeA : TypeB

// Verbose TS
type HasFooString<T> = T extends SomeType 
  ? T['foo'] extends string
    ? TypeA 
    : TypeB
  : TypeB
```

Or most similar to my actual use case:

```
type AnchorLike = 'a' | React.ComponentType<{ href: string }>;

type TestAnchor<T extends React.ElementType> = 
(T extends AnchorLike && React.ComponentProps<T> extends {href?: string})
  ? 'anchor' 
  : 'not anchor'

// Verbose TS
type TestAnchor<T> = T extends AnchorLike 
  ? React.ComponentProps<T> extends {href?: string}
    ? 'anchor'
    : 'not anchor'
  : 'not anchor'
```

I know this is possible with nested "ternary" operators, that can get pretty verbose. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you want `DoubleCheck<"a"|0,"b"|1>` to be? You should probably write a version with nested conditional types that behaves exactly as you want for unions (keeping in mind [distributive conditional types](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) exist) and then someone can maybe write a less verbose version.  If I suggest, say, `[T, U] extends [number, string] ? SomeType : never`, that *might* suffice, but without an already functional `DoubleCheck` I can't say for sure.  Ideally you'll put a [mre] in here (and define your types).

Comment: Added an additional example, more similar to my use case. I think your suggestion of checking `[T, U] extends [number, string]` is pretty close

Comment: Here, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9jj3m).  Could you put that in the question?

Comment: And then note that [my suggestion does not work](https://tsplay.dev/mMXXZN).  To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to emulate nested distributive conditional types with a single conditional type.  So the answer here is "no, sorry"

Comment: Conceptually a distributive conditional type is like a `for` loop that iterates over union members, so this question is like asking if you could collapse `for (let i of iArr) { for (let j of jArr) { } }` into a single `for` loop... the answer is probably yes, but not anything I'd think of as *less verbose* (especially the implementation of the thing generating the cartesian product of unions).  How would you like to proceed here?